# Gödel's Completeness Theorem for uncountable domains

Tags: first-order-logic, predicate-logic, formal-proofs

My texts give a proof Gödel's Completeness Theorem for the predicate calculus for countable domains.  The theorem briefly says, if a predicate letter formula is valid in the domain of the natural numbers, then it is provable in the predicate calculus.

How do we extend this theorem to arbitrary (i.e. potentially uncountable) domains? The Löwenheim-Skolem theorem only says that if a sentence is satisfiable in some non-empty domain, then it is satisfiable in the natural numbers.  Is there a theorem that says if a sentence is *valid* in any non-empty domain, it is valid in the natural numbers?

Comment: I realize that the theorem I proposed has to be wrong.  For we can write a sentence that describes the order of an infinite set in one sentence with an undefined predicate as the order relation. (i.e. irreflexivity, transitivity, and Archimedean property). The negation of this sentence is valid in any finite domain, but is not valid in the natural numbers.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan "Corollary 1. Every predicate letter formula $G$ which is valid in the domain of the natural numbers is provable in the predicate calculus." *Kleene* Introduction the Metamathematics

Comment: thats exactly what the completeness theorem says.

Comment: I must be misunderstanding at least one of the words in that claim then. Does "predicate calculus" mean first-order logic? Does "the natural numbers" mean the standard model of PA? In that case, for example $\text{Con}(PA)$ is valid in the standard model but not provable from Peano arithmetic. How is this not a counterexample to that statement as written?

Comment: Oh yes. Predicate Calculus is referring to the pure predicate calculus.  Valid in the natural numbers means that every model in the domain of the natural numbers satisfies a pure predicate letter formula.  This is really a statement about countable models, but the proof presented uses arithmetical properties of the natural numbers in its "construction" (the proof is not entirely constructive).

Comment: I have no idea what "pure predicate calculus" means if it doesn't mean first-order logic or a specific first-order theory of some kind. And what does "model in the domain of the natural numbers" mean? Do you just mean a countable model? This is *extremely* confusing terminology if so; in this context, talking about "the natural numbers" as a model of a first-order theory, anyone would assume you were talking about the natural numbers as a model of Peano arithmetic specifically. If you mean "countable model" then say that!

Comment: yes i mean countable model.  also pure predicate calculus refers to first order logic without other axioms (i.e. without peano axioms).  Isn't it standard in model theory when stating something is satisfiable to DISPLAY such a model in another system.  The proof requires constructing a model that satisfies an irrefutable formula $F$.  We construct this model with a domain of the natural numbers. but this can be translated to any countable set using choice.  This is just the method of the proof presented in the text.  It loosely follows Hilbert-Bernays and Henkin